# Regular expression breakpoint in GDB

Tags: regex, debugging, gdb

I am trying to set breakpoints on all functions that start with "dc_api" but I must exclude functions that start with "dc_api_port_counter" and "dc_api_send_reply".

Regarding the "dc_api_port_counter" exclusion, note that I do want to include functions that start with "dc_api_port_something".

I used regex online tester and came up with the following regex:
dc_api_(?!port_counter|send_reply).*

However, when using it, I get the following error:

```
>(gdb) rbreak dc_api_(?!port_counter|send_reply).*
>!port_counter|send_reply).*: event not found
>(gdb)
```

Comment: gdb uses grep-style regexes, so it does not understand the negative lookahead with (?!...). Unfortunately, there is no other way to negate multiple-character sequences in regexes, so I don't know how to do what you want either...

Comment: related docs: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_28.html

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple, built-in way to do this.  However, it can be done a couple of ways.

First, use `rbreak` to set "too many" breakpoints.  Then, the trick is to find an automated way to delete the extra breakpoints.

A straightforward way to do this is to write a bit of code in Python that loops over all the gdb breakpoints.  For each breakpoint it would examine the `location` attribute, and, if it should be excluded, call the breakpoint's `delete` method.

Answer (score 1):

GDB has convenience functions, https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html, and the $_regex(str, regex) function will correctly handle regex expressions.  However, this might be intended for use as the conditional in conditional breaks.