# How to catch all exception types except one using GDB?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I'm aware of `_catch throw_` or even `_catch throw MyExceptionType_`.

What I need is everything else than a certain exception type.

Answer (score 3):

Since gdb uses a regular expression for the exception string, you could use `catch throw (?!MyExceptionType)` (this will match any exception except for exactly "MyExceptionType")

See also [Match everything except for specified strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404010/match-everything-except-for-specified-strings/2404025#2404025)

Comment: I have checked your answer and it does not work. Seems like `gdb` does not support  the negative lookahead with (?!...). So `catch throw` with the negative lookahead does not work (see also a comment to https://stackoverflow.com/q/34790499/184968)

Comment: I tested it myself and it worked (it said "C++ catchpoint not caught" or something like that iirc).

Comment: @GabrielRavier I wrote a test where I throw exceptions of 2 different types MyExceptionType and TheirExceptionType. When I set `catch throw (?!MyExceptionType)` program does not catch both of them.

Comment: struct MyExceptionType  {};
struct TheirExceptionType {};

int main() {
    try {
        throw MyExceptionType{};
    } catch (MyExceptionType&) {
    }

    try {
        throw TheirExceptionType{};
    } catch (TheirExceptionType&) {
    }
}

Comment: Should I edit it to clarify its wrongness or just remove it ?

Comment: (gdb) catch throw (?!symphony::smc::eqNW::calculateInputException)
Junk at end of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a condition for the breakpoint on *catch throw*, look at [break condition](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/unix/unixguide/infohtml/gdb/Conditions.html#Conditions)